# What is the recommended ram for an ArcServer 9.3 box?

Tags: arcgis-server

I've dug around on the ESRI site for a while and can't find a conclusive answer.  Can someone tell me what ESRI's recommenced RAM is for an server running ArcServer 9.3, with hopefully a link to document it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all dependent on your server setup and DB setup.
http://wikis.esri.com/wiki/display/ag93bsr/ArcGIS+Server#ArcGISServer-ServerRequirements

Answer (score 3):

It depends on many factors such as the average and peak number of concurrent users, their typical usage scenarios (read-only vs. editing, whether you will need non-pooled services or not) and such.

Contact your local ESRI distributor or ESRI directly, the can provide you with an Excel spreadsheet which takes some of these factors into consideration and suggests optimal hardware, it might be of some help.